# CSS style base on route - Angular2

Tags: javascript, css, angular

On the home page I want my logo to be 3x as big. Then when you select a menu option and the router opens a different page it should shrink down to normal size again.

I was trying to do it by setting a variable to the page name and having the CSS change based on that.

```
<li [class.homeLogo]="home === 'Home'">
```

The problem is if someone types the route into the browser URL instead of clicking on the menu button it throws the whole thing off. It also resets if the page is refreshed.

Is there a way to access what route is currently being displayed so that I can ensure the CSS is tied to the page and not a variable?

Answer (score 0):

The $location service parses the URL in the browser address bar (based on the window.location) and makes the URL available to your application. Changes to the URL in the address bar are reflected into $location service and changes to $location are reflected into the browser address bar.

The $location service:

Exposes the current URL in the browser address bar, so you can

- Watch and observe the URL.
- Change the URL.

Synchronizes the URL with the browser when the user

- Changes the address bar.
- Clicks the back or forward button (or clicks a History link).
- Clicks on a link.

Represents the URL object as a set of methods (protocol, host, port, path, search, hash).

For more information see Developer Guide: [Using $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Answer (score 0):

I would set the class at a higher point—say, the `<body>`.

```
<body class="{{controllerName}}">
```

Then you can control your logo size.

```
.logo {
  // regular old logo size
}

.home .logo {
  // 3x, baby!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `...`
})
export class AppComponent {
  @HostBinding('class.homeLogo') isHome:boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    router.changes.subscribe(() => {
      this.isHome = getCurrentRoute() == '/home';
    });
  }
}
```

then you can use global style like

```
<style>
  .logo {
    .... /* make it small */
  }
  .homeLogo > .logo {
    .... /* make it big */
  }
</style>
```

or a local style

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: [`
    :host .logo {
      .... /* make it small */
    }
    :host(.homeLogo) {
      .... /* make it big */
    }`
  ],
  template: `...`
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to this `@Directive` I have wrote. You should only change it to fit you needs.

```
    import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core'; 
import {Router, NavigationEnd} from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
    selector:  '[if-routes]'

})
export class IfRoutesDirective implements OnInit { 

    @Input("if-routes") routes : string[] = [];
    @Input("unless-routes") unlessRoutes : string[] = [];
    @Input("apply-styles") applyStyles : Object; 

    constructor(private _router : Router, 
                private _elemRef : ElementRef, 
                private _renderer: Renderer) {    
    }

    ngOnInit() { 
         //console.log(this.routes); 
         //console.log(this.unlessRoutes);

         this._router.events.subscribe(evt => {
           if(evt instanceof NavigationEnd) { 
                var url = evt.urlAfterRedirects;
                //console.log(url);
                if(this.routes.indexOf(url) >= 0 || this.routes.indexOf('**') >= 0) { 
                    // add element to DOM
                    // console.log("if routes matched!"); 
                    this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._elemRef.nativeElement, "display", "block"); 
                }  
                if(this.unlessRoutes.indexOf(url) >= 0 || this.unlessRoutes.indexOf('**') >= 0) { 
                    // remove element from DOM
                    // console.log("unless routes matched!");
                    this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._elemRef.nativeElement, "display", "none"); 
                } 

                if(this.applyStyles != null && ( this.routes.indexOf(url) >= 0 || this.routes.indexOf('**') >= ) ) { 

                    if(this.unlessRoutes.indexOf(url) <0) { 
                        // apply given styles to current DOM element 
                        for(var style in this.applyStyles) { 
                             this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._elemRef.nativeElement, style, this.applyStyles[style]); 
                        };
                    }
                } 
           }
        });
    }

}
```

Example usage:

```
<header-bar [if-routes]="['/some-route']" 
            [apply-styles]="{'position': 'fixed', 'margin-top' : '0px', 'margin-left' : '0px'}">
Loading header...
</header-bar>
```